# Two requests inside a service in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

Currently I'm working in a project where I'm trying to build a service in express which calls another two external EP. I have a trouble here, because express shows me an error that I can't understand. But I suppose, the way I'm working it should be wrong.
So

```
app.get("/items/:id", (req, res) => {
  return request.get({
    url: `https://myapi.com/${req.params.id}`,
    json: true
  },
  (error, response) => {
    if(error) {
      return res.send("Error ocurred");
    }
    const itemDesc = request.get({                        // Here I'm trying to do the second call and use it later
      url: `https://myapi.com/${req.params.id}/description`,
      json: true
    },
    (error, responseDesc) => {
      return responseDesc
    });

    const itemDetails = response.body;
    const strPrice = itemDetails.price.toString().split('.');
    const numberPrice = parseInt(strPrice[0]);
    const floatPrice = strPrice[1] ? parseInt(strPrice[1]) : 00;

    return res.send({
      id: itemDetails.id,
      title: itemDetails.title,
      price: {
        currency: itemDetails.currency_id,
        amount: numberPrice,
        decimals: floatPrice,
      },
      picture: itemDetails.pictures[0].url,
      condition: itemDetails.condition,
      free_shipping: itemDetails.shipping.free_shipping,
      sold_quantity: itemDetails.sold_quantity,
      description: itemDesc                     // Here I'm using the variable of the previous request
    });
  });
});
```

Basically, the error I get is that I can't do two calls. I know that because if I remove the nested request, it works.
The error I get is the following:
[image]

My question is: Is there any way to do two external request inside the same method?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't send two response in one request handler. Where is line 52 in `index.js`?

Answer (score -1):

it's cleaner if you do it with async await in your case.
modify your code like this

```
app.get("/items/:id", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const promise1 = fetch(`https://myapi.com/${req.params.id}`).then(data => data.json())
    const promise2 = fetch(`https://myapi.com/${req.params.id}/description`)

    const [itemDetails, itemDesc] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
    const strPrice = itemDetails.price.toString().split('.');
    const numberPrice = parseInt(strPrice[0]);
    const floatPrice = strPrice[1] ? parseInt(strPrice[1]) : 00;

    res.send({
      id: itemDetails.id,
      title: itemDetails.title,
      price: {
        currency: itemDetails.currency_id,
        amount: numberPrice,
        decimals: floatPrice,
      },
      picture: itemDetails.pictures[0].url,
      condition: itemDetails.condition,
      free_shipping: itemDetails.shipping.free_shipping,
      sold_quantity: itemDetails.sold_quantity,
      description: itemDesc // Here I'm using the variable of the previous request
    });

  } catch (
    res.send("Error ocurred")
  )
  
});
```